# Multiple SVGs in external file - how to specify in img tag which one?

Tags: html, svg

I want to refer in HTML src tag to one of multiple svg elements in external file. Is it possible? How?

In HTML page:

```
<img src="svg5.svg#svg2" height="100px" width="100px">
```

Here is svg5.svg file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg>
<svg id="svg1" width="100" height="100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="blue">
</svg>
<svg id="svg2" width="100" height="100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="red">
</svg>
```

---

### **9/1/2019 Update:**

Tried also the following, as per @BeccaH advice:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 
<h1>SVG</h1> 
<img src="svg5.svg//svg[@id='svg2']" height="100px" width="100px"> 
</body> 
</html>
```

**It didn't work.**

Comment: Can you include the HTML code that you have tried already, along with the name and location of the external file you are trying to use. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have added the code I've tried. I hope it's now clear what and how I've tried to achieve

Comment: Multiple nested svg tags definitely won't work. Using `xuse` on svgs might work, but you cant do it with an img tag. (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use to see how it _can_ work)

Comment: @somethinghere: I don't see how the "use" tag is going to help me. The example at the top in developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use is simply creating three images. How do I refer only to one of them?

Comment: One hidden SVG with all the illustrations in it can be used by other SVG tags to reference IDs from the original, cutting down on duplication. Thats as good as it gets.

Comment: Do **10 SVG images require 10 SVG files?** There is no way to **put all 10 images into one SVG file**, and then somehow in a HTML file to refere to them separately??

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash in HTML and never has.